# ng-repeat call controller function too many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I have next code (events is array):

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events">
    <td>
        <span time-ago="{{event.TimestampSec}}"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{prepareAlertValue(event.AlertValue)}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

time-ago - my custom directive. It is executed *events.length* times.

My controller:

```
...
window.callPrepareAlertValueCount = 0

$scope.prepareAlertValue = function(value) {
    window.callPrepareAlertValueCount++;
    if(safemineHelper.isFloat(value)) {
        value = (~~(value * 100)) / 100;
    }
    return value;
}
...
```

After list is shown - I see that *callPrepareAlertValueCount* grows. Console log:

```
 > callPrepareAlertValueCount
 < 41890
 > callPrepareAlertValueCount
 < 46150
 > callPrepareAlertValueCount
 < 480315
```

Please, can someone explain why is prepareAlertValue executed all time. 
Do I need to write directives for each formatter function?

Comment: maybe i'm misreading, but you say the problem is it's executed events.length times? is that not the expected behavior in a loop?

Comment: It is being executed multiple time because it is inside the tr tag that is having ng-repeat if you would put it outside the tr it will be called once only.

Comment: The problem is that function callPrepareAlertValueCount executes all time. About 3000 times per second

Comment: that is because of digest cycle of angular, try `{{::prepareAlertValue(event.AlertValue)}}` bindonce directive will run only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct what ever you bind on html, it gets called on each digest cycle run by angular js.

Use `{{::prepareAlertValue(event.AlertValue)}}` bind once directive that will execute that function only once.

> **Note** Bind Once only work for above Angular 1.3+

Comment: Looks like a true ;) but I got next error - 
Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [::prepareAlertValue(event.AlertValue)] starting at [::prepareAlertValue(event.AlertValue)].

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: @gleb Any way you can upgrade angular to 1.3 because its stable release :) Thanks. Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not know whats going on inside prepareAlertValue() so
it needs to call this function on every digest

Comment: @pankajparkar has an interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

`callPrepareAlertValueCount` is a global variable on the window, and is updated whenever `prepareAlertValue` function is called.

The catch is, it's called whenever a digest cycle takes place. Whenever a change is made, such as a click event is triggered (through Angular with `ng-click`), or your `events` array is altered, that triggers a $digest cycle. When a $digest is triggered, the function reevaluates as all angular watchers are being reevaluated, and increments `callPrepareAlertValueCount`. So it happens many more times than `events.length`.

Basically, you shouldn't be relying on keeping a counter that way, since you have no control on how many times the $digest cycles are run.

Here's a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11333/) that demonstrates this.

Comment: If I remove increment for callPrepareAlertValueCount and write console.log('here') instead, it will call about 3000 per seconds too. So I'm sure that problem doesn't connected to callPrepareAlertValueCount. (When I write console.log('here') my computer freezes)

Comment: @Gleb Exactly my point... The function gets called many many times and your counter is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

You may stop calling controller functions inside ng-repeat. or if you want to call the controller function inside a loop(ng-repeat), then use proper conditions(in your controller), if true then call the function if you don't , then it will be calling the controller function every time.

Comment: i think you may read about angular digest cycle https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/